# AngularJS scope not updating in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS directive that needs an isolate scope plus access to the `$parent` scope. The parent scope has data which changes after an ajax call completes.

In my directive's linking function, I have:

```
scope.loading = scope.$parent.contractData.People.loading;
```

but when the parent's `contractData` value changes, `scope.loading` does not update. I've even tried using `scope.$watch`, but that does not get notified of the change either.

In my directive's template, I am using `ng-show`. The following template works as expected:

```
<span ng-show="$parent.contractData.People.loading">loading</span>
```

But this does not work (because the scope never finds out about the data change):

```
<span ng-show="loading">loading</span>
```

I need to be able to set up a scope variable in my directive, because 'People' will change, depending on data passed into the directive's attributes. Otherwise I would just stick with the working example above.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up the HTML for the directive like:

```
<div mydirective="contractData.People.loading"></div>
```

And within the directive itself, create an isolate scope binding to the `loading` property

```
scope: {
    isLoading: '=mydirective'
},
// rest of directive
```

This creates a property on the directive's local scope that is bound to the attribute expression.  Then you can refer to that scope property in the directive's template like:

```
template: '<span ng-show="isLoading">loading</span>'
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/P29Fz/)